# Recharts eslint error missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, recharts

I'm a novice react developer. eslint provides the following error(s)

```
Line 37:11:  'x' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
Line 37:14:  'y' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types
...
```

which refers to line 2, of the following code snippet

```
const customLabel = (props) => {
    const { x, y, width, height, value } = props;

    return (
        <text
            x={x} y={y} fill={"white"}>
            {value.toLocaleString()}
        </text>
    );
};
```

The `customLabel` is for the recharts library

```
<Bar
    dataKey={metadata.dataKey}
    name={metadata.name}
    unit={data.xAxisInfo.unit}>
    <LabelList dataKey={metadata.dataKey} content={customLabel} />
</Bar>
```

I'm using the `<LabelList content={customLabel} />` inside the `<Bar />` component exactly like [the example in the documentation](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/BarChartWithMinHeight). I can't declare the prop types in an interface as `customLabel` is then unassignable to `ContentRenderer<LabelProps>`. Suppressing eslint isn't an option unfortunately.

Both code snippets are in the same functional component